# Отсутствуют AccountController и папка Account во Views при использовании Identity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

При создании проекта ASP.NET Core(2.1) Web Application => MVC Не нахожу в архитектуре AccountController и папки Account во Views. Авторизацию сделал, проходит, но внести изменения в оформление и функционал страниц логина не могу, так как не нахожу их в проекте. Подскажите, где их найти, или как вносить изменения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с Asp.Net Core 2.1, Identity вынесена в отдельную либу (Razor Class Library), поэтому нет ни контроллеров, ни представлений.

Чтобы кастомизировать Identity, нужно использовать Scaffolder - он позволяет выборочно добавлять исходный код нужных компонентов в проект, чтобы его можно было править.

Вот, как это сделать:

> - From **Solution Explorer**, right-click on the project > **Add** > **New Scaffolded Item** (*Создать шаблонный элемент*).
> - From the left pane of the **Add Scaffold dialog**, select **Identity**(*Удостоверение*) > **Add**.
> - In the **Add Identity dialog**, select the options you want.

Подробности в [документации](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio#scaffold-identity-into-an-mvc-project-with-authorization).